# What does 'to come over one's hoot' mean?

Tags: idioms, idioms-in-context

I came across the phrase 'to come over one's hoot' several times while watching a British TV series and I can't get the meaning of it from any definition of 'hoot'.

The context was like this:

A and B are talking on the line in their workplace and when B doesn't follow A's instruction, A gets agitated and says this line: "B, I'm going to **come over your hoot** and broadcast this(=B's serious mistake)."

As they're talking on the phone and work in the same building, I presume this might mean that A is going to come over to B's desk but I'm not very sure.

I also wonder how any meaning related to this scene could come from the word 'hoot', for all I could find out about its definition as a noun were a. a shout, outcry b. honking sound c. laugh or a cause of laughter d. a cry of an owl.

So could you help me find out the meaning of the phrase (or idiom) **to come over one's hoot** and explain how come it has such meaning?

Comment: "a British TV series" which one? don't make us guess.  Is it possible that you (or the person who wrote the transcript) misheard "hood" (a deliberate Americanism, and a shortening of neighbourhood)

Comment: Googling the two separate strings [**"I'm going to come over your" "and broadcast this"**](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I%27m+going+to+come+over+your%22+%22and+broadcast+this%22&oq=%22I%27m+going+to+come+over+your%22+%22and+broadcast+this%22&aqs=chrome..69i57.10351j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) shows it's from the "shooting script" for [a British-American television drama series called "Industry"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Industry_(TV_series)). I don't recognise ***hoot*** as BrE slang, unless it's "eye dialect" for ***hut*** in a Midlands/Northern accent, so maybe James is right.

Comment: ...actually, I've just dowloaded the pdf of that script and searched for "hoot". It already occurred earlier in **WHAM! Phones ring. Theo’s voice can be heard on the hoot, announcing the result**, and twice more *after* the cited instance as **Duncan patches into her hoot. His voice broadcasts through her intercom** and lastly as **Daria and Eric look at her due to Duncan’s voice on her hoot.** Perhaps it just means (telephone) loudspeaker, I dunno. Probably shortened from ***hooter***, whatever the referent.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question on the grounds that if the OP was really paying attention to the source, he'd have asked what it meant when the word "hoot" was ***first*** used (earlier in the text).

Comment: Thanks for all your comments! First of all, my apologies for making you guessing by not mentioning the title of the series! I thought some might not want to see any spoiler and because this is English Language Learners forum, that information might not be relevant to what I was asking as long as I described the context.

Comment: And oh, I didn't know I could find a shooting script when I googled Industry s01e02 script and only could read one from Subs like Script. The stage direction FumbleFingers cited helped me a lot! So thank you so much and when I come across a similar situation, I'll look for if I can find any shooting script as well so I can get more context from it! Thanks again for your help and sorry if my question was not thorough enough!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm British, and I believe I have an ear for UK regional dialects, and I had never heard 'hoot' used in this way. I was ready to declare this, and be done, but a little imp said 'Google hoot speaker phone bank'. *Industry* is a TV show set in the finance sector. Mickey Down and Konrad Kay, the show's writers, were a bank analyst and an equity salesman respectively before they left to write for TV. Finance sector companies, banks, etc use systems informally called 'Hoot-n-Holler' or 'the hoot'. They are speaker phone devices where someone can press a button and speak, and be heard at once by colleagues similarly equipped.

> let me tell you about the “hoot-n-holler”. More commonly called “the
> hoot”, this speaker system allows me to speak into a microphone at my
> desk in New York and have my voice amplified for all to hear across
> the entire company, not only on the other floors of the New York
> offices but also in London, in Tokyo, in São Paulo… The hoot gets used
> for broadly-applicable announcements, like when there is a major
> headline and one of the economists comes on to provide analysis and
> commentary. It also gets used to execute trades (usually big ones) or
> to call out to a trader who has gone unresponsive to pick up her
> phone. But one of the really cool things about this system of mass,
> live, voice dialogue is that it also creates community. On Fridays, a
> game would be played over the hoot, a sort of lottery in which much of
> the New York office would enter his or her ID card into a pool along
> with some amount of cash. ID cards would be pulled and called out over
> the hoot one by one until there was only one remaining… and that lucky
> winner would take home the entire pot of “weekend money.”

[The Hoot-n-Holler](https://medium.com/@jillcarlson/the-hoot-n-holler-3269fabd09f)